# Rendering a component within another component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, components, render

I am trying to render components inside another component in the following way. Even when I try to render div elements within the component it's not being displayed.

```
const Sandbox = () => {

return (
<div>
<RenderHtml
Title="This is the title"
        Description="This is the description">
<Example message="Hello World" />
        <h1>Render somthing here</h1>
</RenderHtml>
</div>

 );
};

export default Sandbox;
```

Below is the code for RenderHtml component

```
const MyCard = styled(Card)();
const RenderHtml = (props: any) => {
return (
<MyCard>
      <div
        style={{
          display: "flex",
          justifyContent: "space-between",
          flexDirection: "column",
        }}
      >
<Typography variant="h1" sx={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
{props.Title}
        </Typography>
<Typography variant="subtitle1" sx={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
 {props.Description}
        </Typography>
      </div>
    </MyCard>
  );
};

export default RenderHtml;
```

I went through different examples and tutorials couldn't understand how I can render. If someone could help me out with this please.

Comment: Is it the stuff inside `<RenderHtml>` that isn't rendering? If so, can you show us the code for `RenderHtml`?

Comment: @NicholasTower i edited my question including <RenderHtml>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add {props.children} into the component if you want to render what's inside like this:

for Component1

```
const Test=(props)=>{
    return <>
    {props.children}
    </>
}
```

for Component2

```
const Test2=(props)=>{
    return <>
    {props.children}
    </>
}
```

for App.js

```
   <Test>
     <Test2>
       asd
     </Test2>
   </Test>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you render components inside another component, these get passed to the outer component as the prop `children`. For the inner components to have any effect, the outer component needs to do something with the `children` prop, which your `RenderHtml` component currently doesn't do.

For example, if you want the children to be rendered after the title but inside the div you can do this:

```
const RenderHtml = (props: any) => {
  return (
    <MyCard>
      <div
        style={{
          display: "flex",
          justifyContent: "space-between",
          flexDirection: "column",
        }}
      >
        <Typography variant="h1" sx={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
          {props.Title}
        </Typography>
        <Typography variant="subtitle1" sx={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
          {props.Description}
        </Typography>
        {props.children}
      </div>
    </MyCard>
  );
};
```